# Azure web app with different npm script to start app

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I'm trying to publish a node/express app to Azure Web Apps using Github Actions.

I assume that Azure knows how to run a node app because it defaults to "npm run start", but mine is based on a starter kit suite that uses "npm run serve" instead. How can I tell Azure how to run my app once it's deployed?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#configure-nodejs-server? Also you could just add `"start": "npm run serve"`.

Comment: I have read lots of their docs yes, but the MS docs are a sprawling mess and it's hard to find anything there. If the second part of your comment works then that's presumably the right answer so why not just post it as an answer?

Comment: Why the attitude? I couldn't find that information despite searching and it might sound like a newbie question to you but what do you think this place is for? We all have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody pointed out a workaround in the comments but didn't post it as answer so here it is...

You can just point one script at another, so {"start" : "npm run serve"} works perfectly well.